# reduce functions on a dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming, reduce, functools

This might be somehow of a trivial question, but I have a dictionary on which I would like to apply some 10 functions to modify its content.

I think this would be a good case for `reduce` but I cannot seem to make it work.

Here's an example

```
from datetime import datetime
import re
from functools import reduce 


d_ = {
      "dob_partial": "20120314", 
      "service_address_country":"Uni44ed Kind-om"
     }
```

What I would like as a results:

```
d_ = {
      "dob_partial": "20120314",
      "dob": datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 14, 0, 0)
      "service_address_country":"Uni44ed Kind-om"
      "service_address_country_clean":"Unied Kindom"
     }
```

Here's the replicable code:

```
# pre-processing functions

def clean_address_country_code(d):

    key = 'service_address_country'
    d[key + 'clean'] = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z ]+', '', d[key])

    return d

def add_datestr_to_date(d):

    key = 'dob_partial'
    d['dob'] = datetime.strptime(d.get(key), '%Y%m%d')

    return d

# pipeline function to apply all preprocessing functions

def apply_all_preprocessing(fns, dic):

    reduce(lambda fn, d=dic: fn(dic), fns)

    return dic

fns = [add_datestr_to_date, clean_address_country_code]

apply_all_preprocessing(fns, d_)
```

Which works only partially (it applies only the first function in the list `fns`):

```
>>> print(apply_all_preprocessing(fns, d_))

{'dob_partial': '20120314', 'service_address_country': 'Uni44ed K-?indom', 'dob': datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 14, 0, 0)}
```

Comment: Have you created a variable called map somewhere in your code?  maybe try printing the type of map and its value

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll try now.

Comment: Just in case you missed it: map returns a list/iterable. reduce is expecting a callable. What about the error is surprising you? Depending on your  debugging environment, just output the map() so you can see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your lambda arguments are swapped. It should be `lambda value, element: ...`. In your case:

```
def apply_all_preprocessing(fns, dic):
    return reduce(lambda d,f: f(d), fns, dic)
```

Supply the initial dictionary as the last argument to `reduce()`.

Comment: Oh - it worked. When say "it should be `lambda value, element...` element is the element of the iterable we are reducing over?

Comment: Yes. Each element in `fns` will be put into `f`. `dic` will be put into `d` the first time around, then the answer `f(d)` will be fed back to `d` in the next iteration.

Comment: If you have time--- There is one things that i clearly haven't understood, because intuitively I would say why does it matter the order I give arguments to lambda when defining? I think what I did initially intuitively was to go with `lambda f, d: f(d), fns...` because I thought the order at definition time mirrored the order of passing arguments. Not sure i understand tho why it would break.

Comment: The order of arguments are determined by how `reduce()` calls the lambda. It is best to read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Comment: I hope you get a better understanding there. It actually lets you see how `reduce()` is implemented. It's really no different than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to simplify your example to try to answer what I think you are asking.

```
d_ = {"A": -1, "B": 2}

def f1(n):
    return n*2

def f2(n):
    return n**2

...
```

So we have a dictionary `d_` and a bunch of functions (`fi`) that we want to apply to its values; maybe all of them sequentially, maybe only some of them in whatever order. Well, how about this:

```
def apply_all_preprocessing(fns, dic):
    for f in fns:
      dic = {k: f(v) for k, v in dic.items()}
    return dic

fns = [f1, f2]

res = apply_all_preprocessing(fns, d_)

print(res)   # -> {'A': 4, 'B': 16}
#                       |        |= f2(f1(2)) = f2(2 * 2) = 4^2 = 16
#                       |= f2(f1(-1)) = f2(-1 * 2) = (-2)^2 = 4
```

Comment: Thanks! This nudges me in the good direction - I had not thought of using dict comprehension! However, I do not want to modify the original data, I seek to add a k:v pair with the modified data (I do not want to overwrite any k:v) pair.

Comment: @TytireRecubans Yeah, my example above was a bit abstract but you got the point. Happy to have helped.

Comment: This was really good! Thank you - I am working on a solution using your logic :)